# Fetching large query result from bigquery to GCE (google computing engine) takes too long

Tags: python, google-bigquery, throughput, google-compute-engine

The bigquery dataset was created by default so the geo location should be either `us-central1` and `us-central2`. Have a GCE instance created in us-east4-b region and running a bigquery python client to fetch query result (normally belongs to large query result, 300 MBs to 1 GBs) to GCE local memory. Notice that it takes consistently 2-3 minutes to fully fetch the query result which ends up with throughput close to 600 MBs x 10^6 x 8 /150 = 32 Mbps.

The 30 Mbps throughput between GCE and bigquery storage is well below the intra-zone network throughput cap of (4 vCpu) 2 Gbps * 4 = 8 Gbps.  Would bigquery gurus, experts, developers who had same throughput problem help us understand more details? Thank you!

Comment: The slowness is likely caused by paging & parsing the result, not the data transfer speed. We have this issue too - would be great to get a way of quickly moving data from BQ to in-memory arrays.

Comment: yeah, it would be slow parsing and paging. The same query on webUI however shows very quick response time (< 10 seconds) especially when the query is cached ( < 5 seconds). It gave me the impression that bottleneck would be at data transfer between biquery storage and GCE.